# How do I tag an EBS volume using AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am creating an instance with an EBS volume using AWS CDK:

```
BlockDevice durableStorage = BlockDevice.builder()
                                        .deviceName("/dev/sdf")
                                        .volume(BlockDeviceVolume.ebs(
                                                    DURABLE_STORAGE_GB,
                                                    EbsDeviceOptions.builder()
                                                                    .deleteOnTermination(true)
                                                                    .encrypted(true)
                                                                    .volumeType(EbsDeviceVolumeType.GP2)
                                                                    .build()))
                                                .build();

Instance instance = new Instance(
                this,
                "MyInstance",
                InstanceProps.builder()
                             /* other config here */
                             .blockDevices(List.of(durableStorage))
                             .build());
```

How do I tag the EBS volume? The `Tag` static method requires a `Construct`, which I can't find on the `BlockDevice`, e.g. I want to do something like this:

```
Tag.add(durableStorage, "cdk", "true");
```

Answer (score 1):

The only working solution I found so far is using `EC2 User Data` to tag the attached EBS volume:

```js
import * as ec2 from '@aws-cdk/aws-ec2'

// ...

const userData = ec2.UserData.forLinux()
userData.addCommands(
  // Tag volume
  'AWS_INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)',
  `ROOT_DISK_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --region ${props.region} --filter "Name=attachment.instance-id, Values=\${AWS_INSTANCE_ID}" --query "Volumes[].VolumeId" --out text)`,
  `aws ec2 create-tags --region ${props.region} --resources \${ROOT_DISK_ID} --tags Key=${tagKey},Value=${tagValue}`,
)

const ec2Instance = new ec2.Instance(this, 'ec2-instance', {
  // ...
  userData: userData,
})
```

Comment: This approach works well.  It's worth noting that the describe-volumes command will give a space-delimited list of volumes, so if you pass that result unquoted (so it is multiple args to 'aws') it will tag all volumes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not possible to tag volume directly with CDK constructs. Maybe tag will be propagated to the volume when instance is tagged.

Tagging the volumes directly looks to be however achievable by using CloudFormation resources - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.CfnInstance.html

Comment: I try to tag the instance and hope the attached volume would be tag. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: You need to set the `propagateTagsToVolumeOnCreation` prop